# Excel, create a list of distinct unique values

Tags: excel

so I'm trying to create a list of values which are unique.

Sorry couldn't workout how to post it as a table, so its an image! But basically I want column1 whittled down to the results in the Desired Result column. Any entry which exists twice or more should be removed. Only the more unique are to be left. 
I see there are tools in Excel, but none give me this result. A search on the internet shows very complex solutions to this, is it really as complex? what would be the solution here.

[image: image showing desired result]

EDIT:
Thought I'd add, Column A could be two columns. basically I am trying to maintain a list by adding new values to it. but because I will export this list I only want the new unique values. So When *newlist* is added to existing list I only want the unique entries left over.

Comment: understandable steps to a solution based within excel. i.e. no plugin, and I'd prefer to avoid VBA.

Answer (score 3):

try this in B2 and fill down.

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$8)/(COUNTIF(A$2:A$8, A$2:A$8)=1), ROW(1:1)))
```